# ld: library not found for -lidn

Tags: objective-c, xcode

A really strage thing just happened, I've been archiving my app the whole afternoon without problems, to make Adhoc distributions, when I finally change the Profile to Distribution it gave me some errors when uploading, I changed the Distribution profile to a new one, and didnt make any more changes and when I Archived it again it gave this error

> ld: library not found for -lidn

I havent found someone getting this very same error, different libraries, but not this one, and all of the answers point to libraries not being added to the project, but I havent added any new libraries... I swear, I could have deleted something from the project or target setting accidentally while changing the profiles but nothing else, how can I fix this? Any idea? How to undo changes in the project and target settings?

Im desperate!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was lucky enough not to commit those last changes, so I discarded those changes and thank god it worked as before. God Save the GIT!

Comment: I'm facing the same issue but git isn't an option :(